# Will redirecting before an Ajax call returns cause issues?

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I have an ajax call where a redirect happens after the call returns (inside the success handler):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/LoadSomeData",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {  
            location.href = "http://mysite.com";                
        }
    });
```

If I do a redirect before the call returns, will the ajax call get cancelled? For example:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/LoadSomeData",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {  
                location.href = "http://mysite.com";                
            }
        });
 location.href = "http://mysite.com";
```

I have a situation where I don't really care to wait till all my data is loaded, and I'd like to redirect immediately.  Question is will redirecting (possibly before the loading has completed) disrupt the loading process?

Thanks...

Comment: Yes, the request will be canceled, so it all boils down to how you handle canceled requests server-side. If you never care about the response, you can try implement it in a way so the server respond directly while processing the request asynchronously in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you redirect outside ajax callbacks, the callbacks will be destroyed and you will redirect immediately. This should have no impact on loading process of the redirected address.

Comment: Thanks.  I was concerned that the loading process would get impacted.  I don't really care that my callback is cancelled (in this case).

Comment: Yes, I observe: a) POST succeeds on the API server; b) $.ajax() success callback fails; c) $.ajax() fail callback, also seems to fail.

Comment: This approach, may be excellent for analytics.  Perhaps link event tracking that doesn't affect performance.

Answer (score 2):

Not having testet that i would assume that the ajax call will be cancelled. you could try ajax calling a php script containing `<?php sleep(10); ?>` or something similar and see if the redirect happens immediately or if it takes 10 seconds.

hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

Browsers are under no obligation to wait for ajax requests to complete, and they don't.